# If a Tumblr blog is deleted, is the subdomain available again for re-registration?

Tags: tumblr

I have a blog on Tumblr (not my primary blog) which I wanted to delete and re-register under a new email ID, so that the two accounts are separate. But if I delete it, will the subdomain be available for registration again - or is it like WordPress.com, which doesn't allow the same name to be registered again?

Comment: Sorry if this question is not appropriate for the Web Apps SE. This SE is the only one I think this question fits in!

Comment: This fits in this SE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just went ahead and created a throwaway account to test this. Yes, once a subdomain is deleted or renamed, it becomes available again for registration on Tumblr.